# Manually add DataGrid cells (without classes)

Tags: wpf, datagrid

my current problem is: I´m trying to make an language editor for my program. For this, i want a multi-language support for editing. The language file is based on "Key" and "Value". So if i load a language file, it should list all entries. Now if i load another file, there should only one new column being added. When the key doesn´t exist, the cell should be empty.

I hope you got it and sorry for the bad english (i really have to improve it ...)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create objects with this signature:

```
public class Entry
{
     public string Key { get; }
     public Dictionary<string,string> Values { get; }
}
```

You just see if a key is present, if not make a new entry, if it is get the existing entry. Then add the value for the specific language to the `Values`, key being the language. Then add a column which binds to `Values[lang]`.